# Counting Hyperlinks

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a tiny problem with Inserted hyperlinks.  If I start with a blank sheet and insert a hyperlink and then copy it to two other cells using two  individual Copy/Pastes:

```
Sub hyper1()
    Cells.Clear
    With ActiveSheet
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("A1"), Address:="http://www.cnn.com/", TextToDisplay:="News"
        Range("A1").Copy Range("A2")
        Range("A1").Copy Range("A3")
        MsgBox .Hyperlinks.Count
    End With
End Sub
```

Three cells get filled and Excel correctly reports the number of hyperlinks as **3**.

However if I fill the second two cells with a single Copy/Paste:

```
Sub hyper2()
    Cells.Clear
    With ActiveSheet
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("A1"), Address:="http://www.cnn.com/", TextToDisplay:="News"
        Range("A1").Copy Range("A2:A3")
        MsgBox ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Count
    End With
End Sub
```

The same three cells get filled, but Excel reports the number of hyperlinks as **2**!!

Which is broken, Excel 2007 or my computer ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Sub hyper3()
    Cells.Clear
    With ActiveSheet
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("A1"), Address:="http://www.cnn.com/", TextToDisplay:="News"
        Range("A1").Copy Range("A2,A3")
        MsgBox ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Count
    End With
End Sub
```

The comma separation splits them into two ranges instead of one

Answer (score 4):

I suspect its because in the second macro, the hyperlink is copied as a single range object as opposed to two individual ranges (like the first one).

Excel will treat this as a Range object (that represents the range the specified hyperlink is attached to). It will therefore count this as one hyperlink instead of two.

You can see this if you click either of cells A2 or A3 after the macro has run (they will both change colour at the same time indicating that the hyperlink has been selected).

Comment: OUCH !!  So if I want to process all the hyperlinks on a sheet, I have to loop over **Cells** rather than **Hyperlinks** ??

Comment: I'm afraid so yes. In reference to your examples, if you were to simply copy one hyperlink from a range containing one cell (Range("A1")) over to another single range of any size, it would still only manifest as two hyperlinks on the sheet in total as the second range its pasted two would be counted as once.

What you could do is define your range like so...

Comment: Sub hyper3()
        Cells.Clear
        With ActiveSheet
            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("A1"),     Address:="http://www.cnn.com/", TextToDisplay:="News"
            Range("A1").Copy Range("A2,A3")
            MsgBox ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Count
        End With
    End Sub

Comment: Apologies, i'm somewhat new to Stack and haven't quite got the hang of posting answers yet!